# flexslider direction nav in a controller and in slider not working

Tags: jquery, custom-controls, flexslider

I've been researching and testing for weeks, but I can't get this code to work. I'm using flexslider (1.8) that is within a theme I'm customizing. I would like to have two directional navs that I'm understanding are manual controls. I built the custom controller first with spans and then with a UL > LI structure. The directional nav arrows work great within the slider, but I can't get the functionality to duplicate in the custom controller. I got the functionality to work yesterday, but it simply moved the directionNav arrows to where the controller is ... I'd like to have both, if possible. I tried updating to the current flexslider.js, but that breaks other flexsliders used in the theme.

I have this in the custom.js file:

```
$slider.flexslider( { 
slideshow: false, 
controlNav: false, 
directionNav: true, 
manualControls: '.custom-controls li a',
controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
} );
```

I have this in the functions.php file that creates the flexslider:

```
echo '<div class="et_media flex-container">';
if ( $media ){
echo '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
foreach( (array) $media as $et_media ){
echo '<li class="slide">';

// if else to get the slides

echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';

/***
 * ul flexslider controller
 */           

echo '<div class="slider_controller">'; // use flexslider custom-controls in ul 
echo '<ul class="custom-controls">';
echo '<li class="photo-title">' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; 
echo '<li class="right">' . '<a href="#" class="next next-nav">' . "next" . '</a>' .  '</li>';
echo '<li class="right">' . '<a href="#" class="next viewnext">' . "view next" . '</a>' . '</li>';
echo '<li class="right">' . '<a href="#" class="prev prev-nav">' . "previous" . '</a>' . '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div> <!-- end .slider_controller -->';
```

Here's the URL (dev url):

```
http://174.132.168.130/~samlewis/?page_id=400#
```

Suggestions greatly appreciated!